# Why the pygments_code.rb plugin is breaking?

Tags: octopress

When I run the cmd: `bundle exec rake generate` for my new octopress blog, it always fails with the following exception.

```
$ be rake generate
## Generating Site with Jekyll
identical source/stylesheets/screen.css
Configuration from /Users/millisami/Code/octopress/_config.yml
Building site: source -> public
/Users/millisami/Code/octopress/plugins/pygments_code.rb:14:in `highlight': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
  from /Users/millisami/Code/octopress/plugins/backtick_code_block.rb:37:in `block in render_code_block'
  from /Users/millisami/Code/octopress/plugins/backtick_code_block.rb:13:in `gsub'
  from /Users/millisami/Code/octopress/plugins/backtick_code_block.rb:13:in `render_code_block'
  from /Users/millisami/Code/octopress/plugins/octopress_filters.rb:12:in `pre_filter'
  from /Users/millisami/Code/octopress/plugins/octopress_filters.rb:28:in `pre_render'
  from /Users/millisami/Code/octopress/plugins/post_filters.rb:112:in `block in pre_render'
  from /Users/millisami/Code/octopress/plugins/post_filters.rb:111:in `each'
  from /Users/millisami/Code/octopress/plugins/post_filters.rb:111:in `pre_render'
  from /Users/millisami/Code/octopress/plugins/post_filters.rb:166:in `do_layout'
  from /Users/millisami/Code/octopress/.bundle/gems/jekyll-0.12.1/lib/jekyll/post.rb:195:in `render'
  from /Users/millisami/Code/octopress/.bundle/gems/jekyll-0.12.1/lib/jekyll/site.rb:200:in `block in render'
  from /Users/millisami/Code/octopress/.bundle/gems/jekyll-0.12.1/lib/jekyll/site.rb:199:in `each'
  from /Users/millisami/Code/octopress/.bundle/gems/jekyll-0.12.1/lib/jekyll/site.rb:199:in `render'
  from /Users/millisami/Code/octopress/.bundle/gems/jekyll-0.12.1/lib/jekyll/site.rb:41:in `process'
  from /Users/millisami/Code/octopress/.bundle/gems/jekyll-0.12.1/bin/jekyll:264:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/millisami/Code/octopress/.bundle/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
  from /Users/millisami/Code/octopress/.bundle/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Which version of ruby do have installed ? What is the version of octopress too ?

Comment: Make sure you `bundle install` or `bundle update` before you attempt to generate your blog.

Comment: I get the same error. Have you find out the answer? How to do about it, please send me a message, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I also get this error.
then I find out code format is not right. in ``` tag.

before:

````
``` objc
view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```
````

after:

````
``` objc
view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```
````

then the error info disappear, I also don't know why